# Can I hang curtains in patched areas of a concrete ceiling?

Tags: concrete

10 drill holes (8mm diameter, 50 mm length) in a concrete ceiling were filled using a high strength concrete repair product and a bonding agent. It's been curing for a whole year.

What are the chances of drilling in the repaired area is secure enough to hang a curtain pole? Since the ceiling is painted is not possible to determine where the patched holes were.

Comment: This for a normal household curtain, maybe total weight 50lbs(heavy)?  Should be okay, unless those holes were made in a small circle trying to make a big hole.

Comment: Thanks! very usueful insight